# Should I cache database data?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, caching

I have a website project using Entity Framework 4.3/Sql Server.

Quite a few of my tables contain semi-static data - stuff that changes infrequently.

My website needs to access data about 100 times per day - some of the data is more expensive - for instance I might aggregate some large chunks of data, but in other cases the data is quite light - for instance lookup tables.

The obvious candidates for caching are the expensive aggregated items, but the semi static lookup tables could be cached too. I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to larger projects - what approach should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching static data to get load off the database is recommended!

You can cache data for the application in multiple ways. One easy way is using static variables, but I would suggest using Application-state like this for simpler scenarios:

```
Application["key"] = value;
object value = Application["key"];
```

To invalidate the cache, you can store a timestamp as well in the cache, and check that to see if 5 minutes passed (or 1 day or something) and then reload the data from the database.

or using the HttpRuntime Cache-functionality:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
public class StaticCache
{
    public static void LoadStaticCache()
    {
        // Get suppliers - cache using the data cache
        SuppliersBLL suppliersBLL = new SuppliersBLL();
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
          /* key */                "key", 
          /* value */              suppliers, 
          /* dependencies */       null, 
          /* absoluteExpiration */ Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
          /* slidingExpiration */  Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
          /* priority */           CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, 
          /* onRemoveCallback */   null);
    }
    [DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public static Northwind.SuppliersDataTable GetSuppliers()
    {
        return HttpRuntime.Cache["key"] as Northwind.SuppliersDataTable;
    }
}
```

For loading the data on startup, do it in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        StaticCache.LoadStaticCache();
    }
```

I would recommend you read: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs for more information.